# scraping imdb top 250 data and replicating in powerpoint using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml

Python27 on windows (32bit)

Hi Experts,

I was referring to this website

- "https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/sanand0/ipython-notebooks/blob/master/Office.ipynb"

I was trying to do the same thing but having this error and stuck.

```
import win32com.client
import os
import win32com.gen_py.MSO as MSO # contains constants refering to Microsoft Office Objects
import win32com.gen_py.MSPPT as MSPPT # contains constants refering to Microsoft Office Power Point Objects
from lxml.html import parse

tree = parse('http://www.imdb.com/chart/top')
movies = tree.findall('.//table[@class="chart full-width"]//td[@class="titleColumn"]//a')
movies[0].text_content()
```

- `IOError: Error reading file 'http://www.imdb.com/chart/top': failed to load external entity "http://www.imdb.com/chart/top"`

Can anyone help here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.imdb.com/chart/top is redirecting to https://www.imdb.com/chart/top, Secured connetion is not supported by lxml.

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29421666/lxml-html-error-reading-file-failed-to-load-external-entity)